# Qt: Custom QListView and live controls

Tags: qt

My custom QListView has delegates to paint the items. I'd like to add a live control to some of the row items (like a QLineEdit), that'll always be present in the row and will automatically scroll correctly with the list.

Since items are not widgets, I cannot assign a control to be a child of an "item", thus scrolling will leave the control in its fixed spot within the QListView widget.

Is there another way?
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the edit widget is created (and positioned) by the delegate when an `QEvent::EnterEditFocus` event occurs then destroyed when a subsequent `QEvent::LeaveEditFocus` occurs and the data is sent back to the model. The delegate should then repaint with the new model data.

Could you expand on what you mean by a "live" control?

Why would you want to have an edit widget constantly open? I think a better way to do this would be to create a delegate which paints the normal view (i.e. for [`Qt::DisplayRole`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)) in a way which you want. Assuming you create your subclass view correctly, the delegate should still update when the model changes.

If you really want to do what you're asking though, I suspect you might be able to by:

- creating your own item delegate (subclassing [`QAbstractItemDelegate`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html))
- reimplement [`createEditor()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#updateEditorGeometry) to use a [QLineEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html)
- then use the delegate's [`updateEditorGeometry()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#updateEditorGeometry)

Have a read of the [Delegate Classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes) section of the Introduction to Model/View Programming though first. The [Spin Box Delegate Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html) and [Pixelator Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-pixelator.html) are worth studying too if you haven't already.

Comment: each row in my listView is similar to an instant messenger's row. Each row represents a contact. and it also has some buttons. The buttons are "hand drawn" because you cannot just put QPushButtons on a listviewRow. The scrolling simply won't work. Some contact rows require a password like pin entry, so that the button can be used. I wanted to put a small edit box next to one of the buttons. and I don't want the user to "double click/click" to make an edit box appear there. I want the edit box to be there constantly and scroll correctly with the listView.

Comment: It sounds to me like this is a problem more suited to custom QWidgets rather than a QListView. Or perhaps a QTableView, or a subclass of QAbstractItemView.

Comment: Probably. I just don't have the time to invent a whole "QListView that has the ability to host live QWidgets per row" concept. I hoped there would be a way to get this done with the current infrastructure.

Comment: Why not just create a 'user' widget with all the controls on, and add that widget to an existing (scrollable) layout widget?

Comment: how do I get to that scrollable widget?